# value from a slider for further computations

Tags: dynamic

I would like to know how to extract the value obtained with a slider for successive computation.
For examle:

```
{Slider[Dynamic[n], {2, 100, 1}], Dynamic[n]}

y=N[Log[n]]
```

and see immediately the value of y using the slider without using Evaluate Notebook.

Comment: Welcome! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Manipulate[N[Log[n]], {n, 2, 100, 1}]

Answer (score 3):

The same way as you are showing the value for `n`.

`Dynamic` is for displaying things.  Evaluate `Dynamic[N[Log[n]]`.  The output will be a *display* (not a value!) that dynamically updates whenever `n` is changed.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Manipulate[myVal = N[Log[n]], {n, 2, 100, 1}]

Dynamic@myVal
```

[image]

```
myTab=Table[N[Log[n]], {n, 2, 100, 1}]
```

> {0.693147,1.09861,1.38629,1.60944,1.79176,1.94591,2.07944,2.19722,2.30259,2.3979,2.48491,2.56495,2.63906,2.70805,2.77259,2.83321,2.89037,2.94444,2.99573,3.04452,3.09104,3.13549,3.17805,3.21888,3.2581,3.29584,3.3322,3.3673,3.4012,3.43399,3.46574,3.49651,3.52636,3.55535,3.58352,3.61092,3.63759,3.66356,3.68888,3.71357,3.73767,3.7612,3.78419,3.80666,3.82864,3.85015,3.8712,3.89182,3.91202,3.93183,3.95124,3.97029,3.98898,4.00733,4.02535,4.04305,4.06044,4.07754,4.09434,4.11087,4.12713,4.14313,4.15888,4.17439,4.18965,4.20469,4.21951,4.23411,4.2485,4.26268,4.27667,4.29046,4.30407,4.31749,4.33073,4.34381,4.35671,4.36945,4.38203,4.39445,4.40672,4.41884,4.43082,4.44265,4.45435,4.46591,4.47734,4.48864,4.49981,4.51086,4.52179,4.5326,4.54329,4.55388,4.56435,4.57471,4.58497,4.59512,4.60517}

**Edit:**

See [LocalizeVariables](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LocalizeVariables.html)

> With LocalizeVariables->False, the variables are treated as global,
>   and can be set and accessed outside the Manipulate expression.

```
Manipulate[myVal = N[Log[n]], {n, 2, 100, 1}, LocalizeVariables -> False]
```

[image]

```
myTab[[n]]
```

> 4.44265

Comment: Ok. But if I want to assign Dynamic@myVal (which is a display) to a new variabale (for example y) to use for additional computations, how can I do that?
My best regards, jack